# « Les pronoms réfléchis se placent devant le verbe », devant=avant?

Tags: sens, indications-de-temps, adverbes, indications-de-lieu

I read in *Grammaire Progressive du Français* written by Maia Grégoire, page 26, that “Les pronoms réfléchis se placent devant le verbe”, for example:

> Je me lave; Tu te regardes;

Here “devant” means “before” when it should mean the opposite, right? “Devant” means “in front of” something? Is this a mistake by the author?

---

J'ai lu dans la *Grammaire Progressive du Français*, de Maia Grégoire, page 26, que « Les pronoms réfléchis se placent devant le verbe », par exemple:

> Je me lave; Tu te regardes;

Ici « devant » signifie « avant », derrière mais, en réalité, il signifie le contraire, pas vrai?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no mistake here, since “devant” can be translated to English as “in front of” (i.e. it refers to space), while “avant” refers to time and can be translated as “before”. It's rather subtle case, because when one speaks, he/she pronounces *pronoms réfléchis* **before** the verb, but when one looks at written text, *pronoms réfléchis* go **in front of** the verb. Generally, both words may be used, it's not big a deal in this case.

---

Je crois qu'il n'y a pas de erreur ici, parce que « devant » s'applique à l'espace et « avant » s'applique au temps. Ainsi, on peut utiliser les deux mots parce que le texte peut être écrit ou prononcé.